# Android - custom files / package

Tags: android

Would like to ask a general questions regarding android

We see more and more Android devices comming and also some Android apps from different external developers

Overall typical the developers of those Android apps delievers a APK file and we can then deploy it through private app - google managed store.
But typical there must also be done some special configuration within config file, before the app is working. So like json file etc where server information etc must be also imported to the device, before app will work

Of course this can be done manually way - but would like to know if there is a smarter way doing this

The most easy way would be to make a package which include the necessary files and that put them in the right location- but as i know this is not possible on android ?

Overall goal is it of course to make installations of these android devices fully automatically, so we don´t have manual to download json files and place them the right places, before the app will work

Comment: You can place as much files in assets as you want.

Comment: I am complete newbie on Android apk. Does any know some kind of tools/tutorials where this is already made, so I can copy this as I don´t learn programming here and now ?

So overall - have an APK, with file1.json file2.json - and then a script that copy those 2 files to "Downloads" folder on internal storage. 

I have created a APK in android studio

Comment: Well start with placing these files in assets. This you do with Android Studio. Can you? Do you know where i'm talking about?

Comment: Hmm I don´t know if i am on the right path. In android studio I have create a project and put the files I would like to copy in /src/Main/res/raw

Comment: We suggested putting them in assets. So in ../app/src/main/assets. You have to create the assets folder yourself if it is not already there. Close Android Studio and create the folder with Windows Explorer.

Comment: I created the assets folder now - could just create it in Android studio

Comment: @blackapps what is the next step if you know?

Comment: That depends on how your want to use these files. Only read? Or edit too?

Comment: If you created assets folder with Android Studio then check full path as it might be wrong. ( Follow the signs ;-)).

Comment: The files should just be read only - and path is fine - checked also in windows explorer

Comment: Use AssetsManager to open an InputStream for a file in assets. Then read from the stream. Thats all.

Comment: just to be sure I did write what my goal is. To get an apk that when launched on a android device, it then copy files from assets folder to internal "Download" folder

Comment: Ok. But why would you copy it to Download folder ? If you only want to read the content of the file you can do that from assets directly. Why are you calling Download dir 'the right location'?

Comment: There is an seperate app that needs to read the file from the "download" folder - so looking for a easy way of getting these files deployed as I want to avoid to do it manually on many devices

Comment: Ok. Then google for how to copy a file from assets to storage. Code has been posted a hundred times. Java and Kotlin.

Comment: The user of the other app then has to select that file. Are you programming that app too?

Comment: Yes I found multiple lines of codes - but where should the script lines be stored to work ? - is there a special folder?

Comment: Script lines? What do you mean? You will program in Java or Kotlin i presume.

Comment: No the app is comming from external developer - and they just told us manually to place the config files in the download folder, so the app will load the right configuration (where there is server info etc)

Comment: just tried an ask chatgpt - and it wrote this that should be used to copy from assets folder - and it created a 60 lines code that should be inserted into MainActivity.java file - does that sounds correct ?

Comment: What do you expect us to say? What do you think we can say?

Comment: @blackapps yes I understand, but as I said, I am very new to this.
Overall the question should be. In The script that must be executed when launching the APK - where must this be placed.
As I understand, when I create the APK file, I have the assets file in the apk and also the script must be placed inside the APK

So my question is : where must the script be placed

Comment: Sorry i have no idea what you mean with script. And for what you wanna use a script. You wil have Java code or Kotlin code. (Third time i mention these languages and you do not tell which you use).

Comment: Yes OK - it is me that have not enough knowledge on this.
But I need some kind of "script" - yes java code as example - to move the files from assets folder to the Internal downloads folder. The java code, how is this created (I don´t need the exact code), but just need to understand how the java code is build into the APK (like in Android studio)

Comment: According to chatgpt it should be like
Open Android Studio.
Navigate to the app/src/main/java/ directory in your project.
Create a new Java class or use an existing one to contain your file-copying logic.

Comment: You will have function that does the work. And call the function in onCreate() of main activity.

Comment: I think I will try and see if I can find a APK where this is already setup such a copy function, and then make it fit to mine

Comment: Finding an apk? What do you mean? Extracting something from an apk? If you have the copy code then start a new project and place or call your code in onCreate() of main activity. Thats all. No idea what you try to solve or are afraid for.

Comment: `see if I can find a APK where this is already setup such a copy function, ` Well i suggested you to google for it. And you would have found java or kotlin code at hundred posts in stackoverflow. Ten code lines ar most. Not sixty that chatgpt suggests. Complete with nice discussions of how to use... Sigh..